# Vue-router is not encoding forward slash

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vue-router, router

I have a route in my VueRouter object that is:

`{path: '/apples/:oranges', component: Example, props: (route) => ({oranges: route.params.oranges})`.

When the `oranges` parameter includes a `/`, it isn't encoded in the URL which is causing problems. Spaces; however, are being encoded correctly (as %20). Why is this? Shouldn't vue-router be encoding all special characters correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to set the value of `path` as a `string` using single quotes:

```
{ 
  path: '/apples/:oranges',
  ...
}
```

Comment: My mistake, path is in single quotes I just neglected to put that in the question.